# ActiveRecord: how to query records created on a specific weekday (e.g. on Mondays, Tuesdays, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to query a postgreSQL database using **ActiveRecord** to get all the records created on a specific weekday (eg on a Friday). My record looks like this:

```
#<PortfoDatum:0x00007fbdcb4d2660
 id: 442114,
 user_id: 96,
 label: "01:20 PM",
 cash_balance: 994540.0,
 created_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2021 13:20:00 EST -05:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 02 Feb 2021 13:20:00 EST -05:00,
 date: "2021-02-02 13:20:00 -0500",
 holdings_snapshot: {"NFLX"=>10}>
```

I've tried so far weaving in the .wday method but have had no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For postgres you can use [date_part](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/date_part.php) where Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.

Eg, to find all users created on a Friday you can use:
`User.where("DATE_PART('dow', created_at::date)=?",5)`

Comment: `date_part` is equivalent to `EXTRACT('dow' FROM created_at)` - which is more standard SQL except dow. Casting to a date is not necessary in either case. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT